# Android how to set captured video to .mp4 instead of .3gp

Tags: android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-mediarecorder

I'm using the default camera to capture video:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE); 
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,MAX_DURATION);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, MAX_SIZE_BYTES);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

How can I set the file container to .mp4 instead of .3gp?

Comment: Did you find soluion?

Answer (score -1):

You can change the `MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY` value to `0`.
Just like this:

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
```